# Illustrator: Change dpi and design size upon exporting to PDF

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, export, dpi, paper-size

I've made a 15' x 10' design that will be printed. The printer told me I should save it as a pdf at 15” x 10” (inches) @300dpi".

I'm very unfamiliar with exporting out files for print (I do mostly digital design) so would anybody be able to point me to a resource that could help me or give me an answer for how I can go about exporting my design at a smaller size (15" x 10") at 300dpi?

Comment: Most likely you dont do anything. Illustrator has no DPI. Raster graphics inside illustrator offcourse have a dpi but each of them must be checked individually anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The printer is not requesting anything unusual, plus Illustrator does a good job of exporting for print via default settings without you needing to have any experience with that. Just do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (Save as), choose PDF from the file type dropdown and 'Press Quality' preset from the export panel. To be absolutely sure also tick the PDF/X-1a from the 'Standard' dropdown.

[image]

Comment: I think he designed a 15x10 feet and want to resample at 15x10 inches.

Comment: @rafael - resampling is for raster, not vector images. The OP is using Illustrator - but the artwork could easily be grouped and rescaled to fit a 15" x 10" artboard before exportng as PDF.

Comment: "300 PPI" is resampling. If it is all vector yes, it would be reescaling.